# Unexpected __rsub__ output when using dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to subtract two dataframes.

The logic I have for `__sub__` behaves as expected, but the logic for `__rsub__` does not output the reverse.

How can I get the `__rsub__` output to match?

```
import pandas as pd

class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5, 6]})

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.data - other

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return other - self.data

base = Base()
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2]})
```

```
# Unexpected output

>>> df - base
                a
0     a
0 -4
1 -5
1     a
0 -3
1 -4
```

```
# Expected output

>>> base - df
   a
0  4
1  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: your implementation of `__rsub__` is never run. You can step through the execution in a debugger to see for yourself (e.g. ipython: `%debug base - df` and then `s`tep through the execution).

The only way to override pandas' logic here would be to make `Base` a subclass of `pd.DataFrame`, as you can learn from [a helpful note](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__rsub__#object.__rsub__) in Python's documentation on `__rsub__` (my emphasis):

> **Note:** If the right operand’s type *is a subclass of the left operand’s type* and that subclass *provides a different implementation* of the reflected method for the operation, this method will be called before the left operand’s non-reflected method. **This behavior allows subclasses to override their ancestors’ operations**

If you really really need to [subclass pandas data structures](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures), learn from a good example like GeoPandas' [GeoDataFrame](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/geodataframe.py).

But I would rather follow pandas's many recommendations *against* subclassing and rather **use composition**, except if I wanted to accomplish something similar to what GeoDataFrame did for DataFrame.